# 'id cannot be null.' error when trying to delete from ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have `Windows` machine, `ElasticSearch 5.0.0` and a standard `PHP` client for `ElasticSearch`, that I installed using composer. Everything works ok, except delete operation. I can not delete by query and as a result get this error message:

> Uncaught exception
>   'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\InvalidArgumentException' with
>   message 'id cannot be null.'

This is how I try to delete:

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$params = [
    'index' => 'layers'
    'type' => 'layers_type'
    'body' => [
        'bool' => [
            'should' => [
                [
                    'multi_match' => [
                        'query' => ["304"],
                        'fields' => ["id"] // not a surrogate _id, by my own id, that is a part of my index properties
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$client->delete($params);
```

So, how can I fix it? Do I need to install any plugin and if yes, how can I do that on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`delete` function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_deleting_documents.html) requires an id since it is meant to delete a single document, that's the reason why you get that error.

In order to do what you want, you need the `deleteByQuery` function instead, but [it has been removed](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/commit/9f3776a224ef4c65e75df7d004ee37361f64567f) in 2.x and not added back (yet).

You can use the [Elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica) PHP client in the meantime. It is 5.0 compliant and [supports the deleteByQuery feature](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/18b0c890c92744bdd5bd47cc1fc229b9dcd83263/lib/Elastica/Index.php#L151-L156).